# Werkzeug doesn't include wsgi module

Tags: python, odoo, werkzeug

I'm trying to run the 6.1 branch of OpenERP in my development environment that is currently running the 5.0 branch successfully. I'm running on Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx.

I've gotten past a few hurdles, but I'm currently stuck on an error caused by `import werkzeug.wsgi` in the `http` module. I added the `python-werkzeug` package, but it doesn't include the `wsgi` module. I looked on the [package's web page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-werkzeug), and I see that my version of Ubuntu gets werkzeug 0.5.1, when the newer ones all have at least 0.6.2. When I compare the source for [werkzeug 0.5](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/c102f866080722e87428616e29c10eb5d4eaefe6/werkzeug/__init__.py) and [werkzeug 0.6](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/d902d2c05a2cb3d7d1f5414fe9c678273f5ffa05/werkzeug/__init__.py), I can see that the `wsgi` module was added between those versions.

How can I get at least version 0.6 of werkzeug running on Ubuntu 10.04? This says I've already got the latest:

```
sudo apt-get install python-werkzeug
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aptitude is often woefully out of date for Python packages, as it seems to be here. You are much better off using `pip`, Python's package management tool. Pip tells me that werkzeug is currently at version `0.8.1`!

First install pip (if you don't have it already)

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

Then install werkzeug

```
sudo pip install werkzeug
```

Easy install is no longer the recommended way to do Python package - you should certainly be using `pip`.

These commands install the packages into your machine's global Python environment. You would do well to investigate `virtualenv`, which creates separate Python interpreters that can have their own packages installed.

Good luck!

Comment: P.s. You should uninstall apt-get's version before you run this, using `sudo apt-get remove --purge python-werkzeug`

Comment: Yes, except that if you had already tried to install a package that depends on it (e.g. OpenERP 6.1) this will cause it to be removed too. I tried `sudo pip install --upgrade werkzeug` and it worked.

Comment: @HosamAly this is precisely why you should be using virtualenv! You can currently only safely use the version of werkzeug that OpenERP depends on. If werkzeug changes substantially and you run that pip command it may leave your system in an unstable state. Conversely, if you choose to leave the system's version you will miss out on features and fixes. Use `virtualenv --no-site-packages <name>` to create a clean dedicated Python interpreter for each project, install that project's dependencies there using `<name>/bin/pip install werkzeug` and run it using the interpreter at `<name>/bin/python`.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about virtualenv; it looks worth trying.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the answer in the [Werkzeug documentation](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/installation/#installing-a-released-version). `easy_install` seems to get it from somewhere else:

```
sudo easy_install Werkzeug
```

Comment: Easy install looks up the package from Python's package index (Pypi - http://pypi.python.org/pypi). However, you'd be much better off with `pip`, which is a far more complete package management tool :)

Answer (score 1):

Installed http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-werkzeug/python-werkzeug_0.6.2-1_all.deb and this solved the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case I could solve it after doing all this:

```
1- pip install -r requeriments.txt
2- pip3 install -r requeriments.txt
3- sudo pip3 install -r requeriments.txt
4- python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
5- sudo python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
6- cd /usr/bin/local and check the available version of python, then
     . /usr/local/bin/python3.7 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
     . sudo /usr/local/bin/python3.7 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Concluding that the reason is the synchronization of the python version to be used.